# writing function which return one element on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, function

So my function_1 takes (name, number, data) and returns a time calculated from the data.

What i need is for functions_2: take (number, data) and return the name which corresponds to a lowest time.

The data is in a form of dictionaries.

Thanks heaps

Comment: What's your code, and desired output?

Comment: so for example:

Comment: You didn't complete your sentence there. What example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.